# Add item to repeating table when user submits?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, sharepoint-designer, infopath-2007

When a repeating table is added to an infopath form, you can add a value to the repeating table by clicking the default "insert item" button.  I want to know if instead of clicking the specified "insert item" you can just click a user added button to add an item in a repeating table?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use code to do so but it is pretty easy (single line). 
http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/10344/37055.aspx (scroll down to the "easier" way)

Not sure if there is a way to do that directly using the interface only but I don't think so.